# Global uniqueness of the solution for ODE $y'(t)=F(y(t))$ if $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth mapping and consider the autonomous ODE

\begin{equation}
y'(t)=F(y(t)) \text{ with } y(0)=a
\end{equation}
for some prescribed vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose that there exists a smooth solution $y(a,t) : \mathbb{R}^n \times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for the above initial value problem for arbitrary $0<T< \infty$. Here, smoothness implies smooth dependence on the initial data as well.

Now, is it somewhat trivially true that since $F$ is locally Lipschitz, the above $y(a,t)$ is the unique smooth solution to the ODE for $a$ in any compact region and any compact interval $[0,T]$?

But, due to arbitrariness of the compact region for $a$ and the interval $[0,T]$, we in fact have global uniqueness for the smooth solution on $(a,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times [0,\infty)$?

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: The solution is unique butis not necessarily defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ for a given value $a$. Example: $x’=x^2$

Comment: Oh I meant to say $[0,\infty)$. I edited the question. Then am I correct?

Comment: It is not correct, for any $a$ Picard-Lindelof only ensures the existence of a solution in a set $[0, t_a]$. So you are correct that your solution will always be unique, but is not necessarily defined in $[0, \infty)$. You can check that for $x’=x^2$ the solution is defined only in a finite interval if $a \neq 0$

Comment: Without any growth assumptions on $F$ there is in general no global solution, as it might explode in finite time. As commented before, $x' = x^2$ is a good example for this.

Comment: Look at my assumption. I assume that there "exists" at least one smooth solution for arbitrary compact time interval $[0,T]$ and any $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, I question global uniqueness on $[0,\infty)$. for any $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by « uniqueness in $(a,t)$?

Comment: It means uniqueness of the solution $y : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ based on my existence assumption and smoothness of $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, Picard-Lindelöf guarantess uniqueness and local existence and your hypothesis ensures existence on $[0, \infty)$

So indeed there exist a smooth function $G(t, a) : [0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $G(t, a)$ satisfies:
$$
G’(t, a) = F(G(t, a))
$$
and $G(0, a) = a$ as a consequence of continuous dependence.